# traverse xmpp iq stanzas in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, xmpp, openfire

I managed to sendIQ and get the response from openfire server.

Now I can't traverse the response for my purposes:

There is a "find" method to search for nodes like "list", "other1", but I need to traverse all the types of nodes containing in the "list". IQ-response looks like the following:

```
 <iq type="get" id="sid_225">
   <list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" end="2012-04-30T22:00:00Z" start="2012-03-31T22:00:00Z">
     <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
      <max>30</max>
     </set>
     <other1> asdf </other1>
     <othern> aasdf </othern>
   </list>
</iq>
```

I need all the node types of the "list". I got so far:

```
$(iq).find("list").children().each(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
}
```

But this gives me the text like "asdf" from the different types of nodes like "other1" and "othern". How can I get the types of the nodes (i.e. "set", "other1") ? I also tried `$(this).val()`) but it doesn't work either.

Please help....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `nodeName` of each element inside your loop:

```
$(iq).find("list").children().each(function () {
  alert(this.nodeName + ' = ' + $(this).text());
});
```

You can access these variables inside the loop like above for each index in the array/object.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7AKL6/2/

Documentation for `.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Documentation for `Node.nodeName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_(DOM)/Node.nodeName

Also note that your XML example has an error in it:

```
<other1> asdf </other>
```

should be:

```
<other1> asdf </other1>
```

to properly close itself.

Comment: thank you very very much for the answer and the assets! I'm new to js and html5, could you suggest me a good MVC framework to structure the js and html code? Currently I have a xmpp connection and can use this connection across different js files if the js files contain $(document).ready() function. Or do you think it's sufficient for a mobile app?